# Trouble Adding subquery

Tags: mysql

Here is the deal.

I have two tables that have hourly rates and unit rates by a phase_no number.  On one table it may have phase 2, 3, 14 and 81 and on the other 2,14,20, 83 I need to add table 1 sum() to table 2 sums but if you look at the results below you will see although i call out coalese it still produces NULL which you cannot apply math to.   Hopefully you can see what I am getting at.

```
SELECT ru.phase_no,
        ROUND(SUM(ru.units * ru.rate) * 0.75, 2) , (SELECT 
                    ROUND(SUM(rh.hours * rhh.rate) * 0.75, 2)
                FROM
                    rates_hourly_required rh
                        JOIN
                    rates_hourly rhh ON rhh.id = rh.rates_hourly_id
                WHERE
                    rh.project_id = ru.project_id and rh.phase_no =ru.phase_no group by rh.phase_no,rh.project_id)
    FROM
        rates_unit_required ru
    WHERE
        ru.project_id = 67320
    group by ru.project_id, ru.phase_no
```

[image]

Maybe there is a better way to approach this query.

Comment: Where do you use `COALESCE()`?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` rather than a correlated subquery

```
SELECT ru.phase_no, 
    ROUND(SUM(ru.units * ru.rate) * 0.75, 2) AS ru_total,
    IFNULL(rh_total, 0) AS rh_total
FROM rates_unit_required AS ru
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT rh.phase_no, ROUND(SUM(rh.hours * rhh.rate) * 0.75, 2) AS rh_total
    FROM rates_hourly_required rh
    JOIN rates_hourly rhh ON rhh.id = rh.rates_hourly_id
    WHERE rh.project_id = 67320
    GROUP BY rh.phase_no
) AS rh ON rh.project_id = ru.project_id AND rh.phase_no = ru.phase_no
WHERE ru.project_id = 67320
GROUP BY ru.phase_no
```

There's also no point in grouping by `project_id` when you're selecting a specific value in the `WHERE` clause.